# Arrays.sort (with Comparator) - same or different thread?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Is the comparator code in the `Arrays.sort` method called in the same thread as
the call to sort or a different thread?

I am asking this in the context of JDK 8.

I think the answer is that it's called in the same thread but I am not 100% sure. I would be glad if the person answering this question provides some references or some other kind of detailed explanation (other than simple Yes or No).

Comment: What leads you to believe that it might be done in a separate thread?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I didn't say anything leads me to believe that. I just met this question and I am trying to answer it. I think the answer is no (just by looking at the code).

Comment: Too bad the source code of this method is locked up and no one could check it :( .... ;) (edit: oh you checked the source?)

Comment: What I mean is, why are you asking this question? Why Arrays.sort and not some other method?

Comment: IMHO lately the people here just put ironic remarks and downvote too too quickly without even thinking too much.

Comment: The [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-byte:A-) do not mention anything about multithreading which suggests that Arrays.sort should run in the same thread it is invoked.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth As I said I met this question and I find it nice because it implies parallelization and multi-threading may be happening behind the scenes. I mainly want to confirm the results of my research on it.

Comment: @MarcinKról Really? Where is it stated that if it's not mentioned there, then it's not multi-threaded. Can you provide some reference. I didn't know this rule.

Comment: You can simply check the source code. The best way to find out :) Doesn't look multithreaded for me.

Comment: @peter.petrov I don't think the rule is written down somewhere but It is an important implementation detail and well written java docs should include such details. And yes, the best way to find out is to check the source code, you can do it easily if you use IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java#DualPivotQuicksort.sort%28int%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29) ; method referenced from Array sort method [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort%28long%5B%5D%29).

Comment: @MarcinKról OK, makes sense to me. Which doesn't mean that I am 100% sure about that too. Still... thanks.

Comment: @Ioan This link is irrelevant, it's not the sort method that uses Comparator. I looked at the source already as I wrote.

Comment: *"Really? Where is it stated that if it's not mentioned there, then it's not multi-threaded. Can you provide some reference. I didn't know this rule."* Ok, since you said I'm not thinking that much, please explain me this: do you _really_ this implementation detail is nowhere mentioned even though it would cause race condition problemens? Really?

Comment: @peter.petrov true. The real method is this [one](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.util.Comparator%29).

Comment: @Tom I didn't say you're not thinking much unless you were the quick down-voter. Not sure what race conditions you're talking about, it all depends how it's implemented. Multi-threading != Race conditions.

Comment: Thinking logically I want to do something after my array is sorted, then I wouldn't expect it to be multi-threaded and it is multi-threaded then it would be clearly document so that user knows what to expect. So, I think @MarcinKról is right that if it is not mentioned then it is not multi-threaded implementation. BTW, answer to your question is clearly "no".

Comment: @peter.petrov *"Not sure what race conditions you're talking about, it all depends how it's implemented."* When you call `Arrays.sort`, then you expect to have a sorted array right after that call. This means the call itself needs to block the current thread, just to spawn own threads to do the sorting? This _may_ improve the performance for quicksort, but I guess only on larger arrays.

Comment: @Tom OK, fair enough. Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: It would be a nice experiment when threads improve the performance for sorting, though. :D

Comment: Why does this question have 6 downvotes? It's not difficult to check the source code, but this has got to be a much better question than average.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. -5 is a good price for learning a few things quickly :) I still don't get why my question is bad though. In fact it's from a book which is well-known and considered pretty good.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Right, I think so too. Well, it has -5 (or -6) because that many people down-voted it :)

Comment: The quick fingers on the downvote trigger indeed show that something's wrong with our community. People should remind themselves that upvote/downvote is something that should be based on the *usefulness* of the question/answer - not on any other criteria!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no. Sorting (in [`Arrays.sort`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort%28double%5B%5D%29)) is implemented with [`DualPivotQuicksort`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java#DualPivotQuicksort.sort%28int%5B%5D%29), from the docs:

> This class implements the Dual-Pivot Quicksort algorithm by Vladimir
>   Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Josh Bloch. The algorithm offers O(n
>   log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause other quicksorts to
>   degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically faster than
>   traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations. All exposed methods
>   are package-private, designed to be invoked from public methods (in
>   class Arrays) after performing any necessary array bounds checks and
>   expanding parameters into the required forms.

and as you can see in [the implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java#DualPivotQuicksort.sort%28int%5B%5D%29) - it doesn't spin up any threads.

Further, there are [`parallelSort`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.parallelSort%28long%5B%5D%29) methods which use the ForkJoin common pool in order to perform parallel execution. This is very explicit and as some of the other commenters mentioned already - the chances of the JDK API to be vague regards such an issue are very slim.

Comment: He meant the sort method which uses comparator, which is [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: @loan in this case the answer is still "no" becuase it uses the legacy [`mergesort`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.mergeSort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29) which again - doesn't use any threads.

Comment: As you got +2 that's good enough for me. Thanks for the confirmation. As I noted I came to the same conclusion, it's single-threaded. Thanks.

Comment: @alfasin I know. I referenced this method in the comment, but peter.petrov said it is irrelevant. Just wanted to say that the explanation doesn't make sense, as it refers to another method.